# Assign values to an array of indexes in Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, indexing

I have an array of size 300x5. In this the column with index 3 consists if some index and column with index 4 consists of corresponding values.

I have created new array in which I am trying to assign the values in index 4 at index 3 locations in this new array. I tried this but it throws an error.

```
new_arr[old_arr[:,3]] = old_arr[:,4]
```

One of the example related to what I want to do

```
new_arr = np.ones((200,1))
new_arr[[2,3,4]] = [22,44,11]
```

It throws an error

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (3,)  could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (3,1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this code : `new_arr[old_arr[:,3]]` you try to access `new_arr` that index come from values are in `old_arr[:,3]` and you got `IndexError`.

Is this help you?

```
new_arr = np.zeros((300, 5))
new_arr[:,3] = old_arr[:,4]
```

For edited question you need `reshape`:

```
new_arr = np.ones((200,1))
new_arr[[2,3,4]] = np.array([2,4,6]).reshape(3,1)
# OR
# new_arr[2:5] = np.array([22,44,11]).reshape(3,1)
```

Comment: This won't work as the indexes are not in order in `old_arr[:,3]`